# How to set up Python and Homebrew?

Tags: python, macos, path, homebrew

I've installed Homebrew on my MacBook Pro (Mavericks), and Python 2.7.6, via Homebrew. How i can set up the Homebrew's path and the Python's path to use the site-packages and version 2.7.6 in my terminal?
I've searched around for a clear answer but the thing it's pretty confusing, because someone say to edit the .profile file, someone else say the .bashrc file. I'm a Mac noob, so any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Python 2.7:

```
$ brew install python
```

This will take a minute or two. Once that’s complete, you’ll have to add the new Python scripts directory to your PATH

To open

```
vi .bash_profile
```

then add

```
export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH
```

More details on this blogpost: http://johnlaudun.org/20120131-change-path-order-of-mac-os-x/

To try if Python is working on your mac or now.

Just run this command on your terminal :

```
python -c 'print "Hello World!"
```

If it prints "Hello World!" on your terminal, then congrats you have made it

Comment: I've already installed Python, so i have to create the .bash_profile file? Where should i create it?

Comment: No ! .bash_profile is already in your mac. Just restart your terminal and open it via (vi .bash_profile), then add that line in your file

Comment: If i type "find .bash_profile" on my terminal it says "No such file or directory".

Comment: Let me know what do you find ?